# Constructor confusion

Tags: c++, constructor

I always think I know C++ pretty well, but sometimes I'm surprised by even the most fundamental things.

In the following scenario, I'm confused as to why the constructor `Derived::Derived(const Base&)` is invoked:

```
class Base
{ };

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:

    Derived() { }

    Derived(const Base& b) 
    {
        std::cout << "Called Derived::Derived(const Base& b)" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    Base b;
    d = b;
}
```

This outputs: `Called Derived::Derived(const Base& b)`, indicating that the second constructor in `Derived` was invoked.  Now, I thought I knew C++ pretty well, but I can't figure out why that constructor would be invoked.  I understand the whole "rule of four" concept, and I would think that the expression `d = b` would do one of two things: Either it would 1) invoke the implicit (compiler-generated) assignment operator of `Base`, or 2) Trigger a compiler error complaining that the function `Derived& operator = (const Base&)` does not exist.

Instead, it called a *constructor*, even though the expression `d = b` is an assignment expression.

So why does this happen?

Comment: Perhaps add a copy assignment operator and a logging statement. ;)

Comment: The answer you picked forgot to mention this happens because you defined the Derived(const Base&) constructor and you are making a downcast... if you did not define this construtor you would get a compiling error when trying to make the assignment as stated in my answer.

Comment: @Zach: the OP is the one who gets her pick, do not worry she has been notified of all answers (and will continue receiving notifications). If your answer is great, it'll get upvoted anyway by careful readers and will soon join the top answers and be visible to future (less careful) readers as well :)

Comment: @Matthieu M.: I am aware of how Stackoverflow works, but with spams of comments some things are easily missed especially when the answer is accepted within minutes of asking the question (at which point it is easy for a person to ignore additional posts). I never suggested Channel72 to change answer, just made sure details were made aware since this is a C/C++ question and typically C/C++ developers want to know what's going on under the hood (the good ones anyway). All of the above is what prompted my comment. Thanks for the explanation the site though :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

d = b can happen because b is converted to Derived.
The second constructor is used for automatic type conversion.
It's like d = (Derived) b

Derived isa Base, but Base isn'ta Derived, so it has to be converted before assignment.

Comment: I didn't say it is a copy constructor. It is a constructor that creates a Derived from a Base. The same that you want in a cast.

Comment: Dismiss that earlier comment, I forgot about the implicit conversion rules & sequences that apply.

Answer (score 6):

assigning base to derived? perhaps you meant (a) by ref (b) or derived to base. This doesn't really make sense, but the compiler is correctly using your (non-explicit) constructor to convert the Base instance to a new Derived instance (which is subsequently assigned into d).

Use an explicut constructor to prevent this from happening automatically.

Personally I think you messed up your code sample, because, normally assigning firstclass base to derived makes no sense without a  conversion

Comment: +1 for the recommendation of `explicit` to actually solve the problem. All constructors should be declared `explicit`, unless there is a good reason not to (if you want an implicit conversion).

Comment: All constructors should not necessarily be declared explicitly especially in the case of empty constructors. Many coding standards throughout industry specify to use the default constructors instead of empty constructors.

Comment: @Zach: it's been bugging me for some time now... I don't understand what you mean by *empty* constructor ? I would have thought that you meant default constructors (ie, empty argument list) but since you directly oppose the two terms, I don't see what you mean :/

Answer (score 5):

There are two interacting features at play here:

- Assignment Operators are never inherited
- A constructor that is not explicit, or a conversion operator (`operator T()`) define a user-conversion that can be used implicitly as part of a conversion sequence

**Assignement Operators are never inherited**

A simple code example:

```
struct Base {}; // implicitly declares operator=(Base const&);
struct Derived: Base {}; // implicitly declares operator=(Derived const&);

int main() {
  Derived d;
  Base b;
  d = b; // fails
}
```

From [ideone](http://ideone.com/cCdvf):

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:7: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘d = b’
prog.cpp:2: note: candidates are: Derived& Derived::operator=(const Derived&)
```

**Conversion sequence**

Whenever there is an "impedance" mismatch, such as here:

- `Derived::operator=` expects a `Derived const&` argument
- a `Base&` is provided

the compiler will try to establish a conversion sequence to bridge the gap. Such a conversion sequence may contain at **most** one user-defined conversion.

Here, it will look for:

- any constructor of `Derived` that can be invoked with a `Base&` (not explicit)
- a conversion operator in `Base` that would yield a `Derived` item

There is no `Base::operator Derived()` but there is a `Derived::Derived(Base const&)` constructor.

Therefore our conversion sequence is defined for us:

- `Base&`
- `Base const&` (trivial)
- `Derived` (using `Derived::Derived(Base const&)`)
- `Derived const&` (temporary object bound to a const reference)

And then `Derived::operator(Derived const&)` is called.

**In action**

If we augment the code with some more traces, we can [see it in action](http://ideone.com/3H9lL).

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {}; // implicitly declares Base& operator(Base const&);
struct Derived: Base {
  Derived() {}
  Derived(Base const&) { std::cout << "Derived::Derived(Base const&)\n"; }
  Derived& operator=(Derived const&) {
    std::cout << "Derived::operator=(Derived const&)\n";
    return *this;
  }
};

int main() {
  Derived d;
  Base b;
  d = b;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Derived::Derived(Base const&)
Derived::operator=(Derived const&)
```

**Note: Preventing this ?**

It is possible, in C++, to remove a constructor for being used in conversion sequences. To do so, one need to prefix the declaration of the constructor using the `explicit` keyword.

In C++0x, it becomes possible to use this keyword on conversion operators (`operator T()`) as well.

If here we use `explicit` before `Derived::Derived(Base const&)` then the code becomes ill-formed and should be rejected by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've defined a constructor for Derived which takes type Base and you are down-casting Base, the compiler chooses the most suitable constructor for the upcast, which in this case is the Dervied(const Base& b) you've defined. If you did not define this constructor you would actually get a compiling error when trying to make the assignment. For more info, you can read the following at [Linuxtopia](http://ftp.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_c++/Chapter14_023.html).

Answer (score 1):

It can't assign value of different type, so it should first construct a `Derived` temporary.